# Sparksql using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

```
val scc = spark.read.jdbc(url,table,properties)
val d = scc.createOrReplaceTempView(“k”)    

spark.sql(“select * from k”).show()
```

if you observe here @1 we are reading complete table and then @3 we are fetching the results based on desired query. Here reading complete table and then  querying takes alot of time. Can’t we  execute our query while establishing connection ?                                                                                                                            please do help me if you have any prior knowledge  about this .

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
var dbTable =
        "(select emp_no, concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name) as full_name from employees) as employees_name";

Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = 
        sparkSession.read().jdbc(CONNECTION_URL, dbTable,connectionProperties);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I try a query of type "(select count(*) from tab1) as t"   its throwing error? May I know the reason?